# Sending codepage(437) printer

Tags: c#, printing, epson

I have an Epson Receipt printer (Epson TM-T88V Serial printer), who's resident font is CodePage 437. I am using Visual Studio 2010 c#, and need to send decimal 178 (Hex 00B2) out to printer.
I tried:

```
var asciiBytes = new byte[] { 0xB2 };
var asciiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
var unicodeString = asciiEncoding.GetString(asciiBytes);
port.Write(unicodeString);
```

The printer just prints "?" for the unicodeString variable.

Any idea on sending decimal 178 to a printer that is using CodePage 437?
(The  'port.Write'  is how I am sending to the serial port.)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [using the overload of `Write` that sends a byte array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I am new to c#. No I have not tried your method, not sure how I would do that. Code example would be appreciated. The last time I wrote code was 30 years ago in FORTRAN. I have not coded since.

Comment: I suppose it would be `serialPort.Write(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)`

Comment: That worked like a champ! You are a magician!

Comment: Glad to help. Now where did I leave my magic wand..